# Drupal 7 - Selecting individual images for auto-cropped image styles

Tags: image, styles, drupal-7, crop

Let's say I have a content type X that has an image for an attribute. I know I can specify different [styles](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/image#styles) for that image (e.g. medium, large, thumbnail), so that crops are automatically made. But can I select/upload a particular image to use? E.g. "I'm not happy with the autocrop for this thumbnail image. I'll just upload my own."

Are there modules that allow this?

Thanks.